# ModelBinding to DataTables Order data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), the ordering data is passed to the server in the form of a double-array of anonymous type. The form data looks like this:

```
order[0][column]=1&order[0][dir]='asc'
```

Is there a proper way to form a C# property in a model so that the model binder can pick up this data correctly? I've tried Object, Object[], Object[][], Tuples, and dynamics. Nothing seems to work.

```
public class Model 
{
    public <What goes Here?> order { get; set;}
}
```

Also, when pulling the order data out from the API, it looks like this (json):

```
[0][0]:0,[0][1]:'asc'
```

Notice there's no 'column' or 'dir' directives.  It would be great if the modelbinder worked with both a JSON push as well as a HTML-encoded push.

Comment: Looks dictionary-ish.  Maybe declare it as an array of dictionary of string?  `Dictionary<string, string>[] order`?  Just a wild guess.

Comment: How are you sending this request to the server?

Comment: @Jasen Through the server-side ajax functionality DataTables has.  It's sending this data to a URL without any special modifications.

Comment: @Peanut did you try with nested model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tmg, a nested model worked.  For some reason it's wasn't apparent to try that first.